# Network drivers for HP compaq

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

I did not find Network dirver for HP compaq dc79000 small from factor
Driver : intel 82567 LM-3 gigabit

Answer (score 0):

Intel has drivers for your card on their [website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=&ProductID=3003&ProdId=3003).

To help you install the driver, take a look at [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Isn't the driver _e1000e_ already present in the kernel? If it isn't working as expected, something else is wrong.